# Compile Node.js v0.11.12-release error on Ubuntu server 12.04.4

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, compiler-errors

I'm clone node.js from git repo and try to compile v0.11.12-release, but there are an error that i don't know how to solved it.The following is the log.

> tericky@XXXXXXXX:/home/gitclone/node$ make
>
> make -C out BUILDTYPE=Release V=1
>
> make[1]: Entering directory `/home/gitclone/node/out'
>     flock /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/linker.lock g++ -pthread -rdynamic -m64  -o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/openssl-cli -Wl,--start-group /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/app_rand.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/apps.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/asn1pars.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/ca.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/ciphers.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/cms.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/crl.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/crl2p7.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/dgst.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/dh.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/dhparam.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/dsa.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/dsaparam.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/ec.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/ecparam.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/enc.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/engine.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/errstr.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/gendh.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/gendsa.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/genpkey.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/genrsa.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/nseq.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/ocsp.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/openssl.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/passwd.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/pkcs12.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/pkcs7.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/pkcs8.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/pkey.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/pkeyparam.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/pkeyutl.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/prime.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/rand.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/req.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/rsa.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/rsautl.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/s_cb.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/s_client.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/s_server.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/s_socket.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/s_time.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/sess_id.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/smime.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/speed.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/spkac.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/srp.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/ts.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/verify.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/version.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/openssl-cli/deps/openssl/openssl/apps/x509.o /home/gitclone/node/out/Release/obj.target/deps/openssl/libopenssl.a -Wl,--end-group -ldl
>
> flock: g++: No such file or directory
>
> make[1]: *** [/home/gitclone/node/out/Release/openssl-cli] Error 69
>
> make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/gitclone/node/out'
>
> make: *** [node] Error 2

**Updated:**

After install g++, everything is fine.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks like you don't have `g++`

Install [build essential](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/build-essential) which is a reference for all the packages needed to compile a Debian package. It generally includes the `gcc/g++` compilers libraries and some other utils

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: looks like link to build essentials is dead